# Visual Studio 2013 cannot find Ms Test.exe for Test Runner, only VsTest available

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-test-runner

In VS 2013 there seems to be no option to select MSTest instead of VsTest in the Test Runner Dropdown which is also grayed out. Is there a way I can add Mstest to this list as was the case in Vs 2010.

Comment: The short answer is probably: No. But I'm a little unclear about the place you're trying to set this option. Could you edit your question and add a little more detail where you're expecting the setting you're trying to change?

Comment: I am trying to change the Settings under BuildDefinition-->Procees-->Test-->Automated tests-->Test Source-->Add\Edit Test Run in visual studio 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ability to select MsTest in the Build Definitions of Team Build 2013 is no longer available in the default build process templates. You can still create a custom build process template that runs the old runner, but be aware that the old MsTest runner is in fact considered deprecated.

The dropdown is disabled and there is no way to enable it in the out-of-the-box build process templates.

Comment: ok, that is what is thought I might have to do, to build a custom template. Agreed will definitely want to avoid it. Thanks